# Creating a WordPress Plugin that generates an access token for my application

Tags: wordpress, access-token, wordpress-rest-api

I am creating a wordPress plugin that generates an access token for my application so that my application will be able to push and pull posts from the users wordPress account.

Can someone please point me into the right direction.
I have tried the application password plugin but we would like the integration process to be a lot smoother

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a builtin API to push/pull data from the the WordPress database. This API of course has access control. See [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/). I think it would be much easier to use this API than implementing your own access code.

Also, I should add that WordPress allows you to replace its builtin authorisation with your own customised authorisation. I don't remember the name of the action/filter hook to do this but I recall seeing this capability when I read the REST API source code.